# Parse tabular data string into array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have got a list of strings :

```
let data = "12 name bd test 13 something bds tests"

console.log(data.split(" "))
```

I am getting an array of string from a string, but I need to get an array of object

My output would be like this :

```
let output = [
  { id: 12, name: 'name', key: 'bd',test:"test" },
  { id: 13, name: 'something', key: 'bds',test:"tests" },
];
```

How can I get the expected output

Comment: Is the structure of the string always like this, number and then 3 words, number and then 3 words, ...?

Comment: I am passing every list of csv coulmn inside input box , then I will generate a link for every 4 strings

Comment: so, yes or no? :-)

Comment: yeah, it will be yes

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your string is always in the same format and nothing is missing you can use [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to chunk the data up and [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to put it back together.

```js
let data = "12 name bd test 13 something bds tests";
let chunks = data.split(/\s/);
let output = [];

while(chunks.length){
  let [id, name, key, test] = chunks.splice(0, 4);
  output.push({id, name, key, test});
}

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use RegExp to split by 4 words chunks:

```js
const str = `12 name bd test 13 something bds tests`,

      result = str
        .match(/\d+ \w+ \w+ \w+/g)
        .map(chunk => {
          const [id, name, key, test] = chunk.split(' ')
          return {id, name, key, test}
        })
      
console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```